# Django 1.5.2 Admin site no add or change buttons

Tags: python, django

I have a blog app inside of my own website app. The blog's objects (Posts, Comments) don't have the Add/Change buttons in the admin interface.

I used to have the admin code inside of my blog/models.py, but after reading [this post](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11918) I have moved the admin code in a separate file named blog/admin.py which looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.blog.models import Post, Comment

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title"]

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)

class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    display_fields = ["post", "author", "created"]

admin.site.register(Comment, CommentAdmin)
```

However despite this change the add/edit buttons are still absent. I have admin.autodiscover() in my main app's urls.py. I also have admin as an installed app.

Comment: Did you `python manage.py syncdb`after moving the code?

Comment: Templates are overridden? Model has no parameter to admin?

Comment: Yes I did. Still same problem... so weird

Comment: `I have a blog app inside of my own website app.` - Can you post your project structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run below command after your changes

```
python manage.py syncdb
#then
python manage.py runserver
```

into your project root directory.

## Edited

You must check your permission column into User section and make sure blog(add/edit/delete) option is given to that user .

Comment: I have done so. It did not change. I have also tried restarting apache/touching the wsgi file to no avail...

Comment: You must check your permission column into User section and make sure blog(add/edit/delete) option is given to that user .

Comment: I am the only user admin. I just checked and I have full permissions on everything. The admin does have the buttons when I'm in debug mode, if that helps.

Comment: That's for trying to help. I realized it was a stupid mistake I added admin.py to a old folder that I wasn't even using anymore. Everything worked after made the change in the correct folder.

Comment: that's fine. go ahead :)